# How exactly ConstraintSet works with ConstraintLayouts in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, constraints, android-constraintlayout

I just began learning Constraint Layout and it's pretty cool, I have come to topic ConstraintSet and got stuck.

I have seen an example of ConstraintSet in developer documentation but I am not able to get the idea, I have implemented the code as it is and it's working but I am really unclear about the concept.

How constraints work in different ConstraintSet is all I want to know about.

Here is what i have done:

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/act_main"
    tools:context="com.reversebits.constraintanimdemo.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_end="364dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />


    <Button
        android:onClick="foo"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> clone.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.reversebits.constraintanimdemo.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:onClick="foo"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> and MainActivity goes here:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintSet;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.transition.TransitionManager;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ConstraintSet mConstraintSet1 = new ConstraintSet(); // create a Constraint Set
    ConstraintSet mConstraintSet2 = new ConstraintSet(); // create a Constraint Set
    ConstraintLayout mConstraintLayout; // cache the ConstraintLayout
    boolean mOld = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Context context = this;
        mConstraintSet2.clone(context, R.layout.clone); // get constraints from layout
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mConstraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.act_main);
        mConstraintSet1.clone(mConstraintLayout); // get constraints from ConstraintSet

    }

    public void foo(View view) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(mConstraintLayout);
        }
        if (mOld = !mOld) {
            mConstraintSet1.applyTo(mConstraintLayout); // set new constraints
        }  else {
            mConstraintSet2.applyTo(mConstraintLayout); // set new constraints
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you want to move around some views after a button click. You define a layout in `activity_main.xml` for example, with the button in it. To get the `ConstraintSet` of the main layout, `mConstraintSet1.clone(mConstraintLayout)` is called. The secondary layout (the layout that you want to display after the button click) is cloned from the secondary layout file, `clone.xml`. That layout contains the same views with the same id's, but with other constraints applied to them.

After the user clicks the button, `foo()` is executed. `foo()` starts an animated `Transition` and then applies the desired `ConstraintSet` to the `ConstraintLayout`, causing the views to move around. Because of the `TransitionManager` call, the movement is animated.